# Conditional formating of groups in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

My goal is to flag (via conditional formatting) any cell with the same 'code' but different 'prices' with in the same 'column'. I have added a screenshot of what the final output should be.

Is this possible in Excel?

Example Output here

[image]

Comment: use COUNTIFS: `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,B:B,B2)<>COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2)`

Comment: Scott - It looks like it also flags blank cells? How do I only flag cells with values?

Comment: How about `=AND(*Scott's formula*, NOT(ISBLANK(B2)))`